# How to change border thickness around images in HelloGallery

Tags: android

I'm not really sure if it's the thickness of the border or the margin around the image that needs to be changed.  I have never worked with styles before, and just created a styles.xml and colors.xml file for the first time.  I have changed the background color to Red, using the code below in image_border.xml.  But I do not know how to change the border thickness around the images in HelloGallery.

Perhaps it's not in this file.  But what exactly needs to be written in the code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" 
        android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Edit:** The answer might actually be a matter of modifying this portion of the code, since I was able to change the border *color* and image size here:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
      ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
        FileList.get(position).toString());
        i.setImageBitmap(bm);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(160, 180));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        i.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: you might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598200/862629

Comment: If the answer is in there, it is like a needle in a haystack to me, since this is literally the first time I have ever tried to adjust the border or even the color of anything in Java or Android.  Is it the shape tag?  I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border around the image actually is background padding:

i.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. A border is called a stroke, you can specify it like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" 
    android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: It appears that the HelloGallery example has a rectangle around the scrolling images, so the XML I posted above might be misleading.  It is the images not the rectangle around them I need to change.  The solution might be in a totally different part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution for you is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/157740b639959c47?pli=1

hope it helps

Comment: It seems whatever I do to that XML segment I posted above effects just the rectangle around the scrolling images in the HelloGallery code.  I was unaware whether the solution was in that segment of code or not, but it appears not.