# Android Gallery Background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I have followed [a gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and have it working fine, but the problem that I need help solving is that I want to change the background colour of the gallery. If I just use:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

then it messes up and I lose the border also. I want to keep the border, but change the colour from the default grey. I've also tried using different resources such as:

```
R.styleable.gallery1_android_colorBackground
```

but that also does not work. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Which gallery tutorial are you following? There are hundreds of them.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getView()` from your `ImageAdapter`add the following attribute:

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I've tried this already, but it also gets rid of the border, which I'd like to keep.

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027663/how-to-change-border-thickness-around-images-in-hellogallery 

I think you have to redefine the border from xml.